# Yup schema with vee-validate and typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-composition-api, vee-validate

I wanna validate an array of objects with yup schema validation, but I have typescript error.

This is my yup schema:

```
const validationSchema = yup.object({
  roles: yup
    .array()
    .of(
      yup.object().shape({
        id: yup.number(),
        title: yup.string(),
        created_at: yup.string(),
        updated_at: yup.string(),
      })
    )
    .required('Role is required'),
});
```

And **Setup** (here I have an error):

```
 const { handleSubmit, errors, meta, setValues } = useForm({
      validationSchema,
    });
    const { value: roles } = useField<RoleType[]>('roles');

    watch(
      () => props.data,
      (value) => {
        if (value) {
          const { roles } = value;

          setValues({
            roles,
          });
        }
      },
      {
        immediate: true,
      }
    );
```

[image]

**RoleType** interface:

```
export interface RoleType {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  created_at: string;
  updated_at: string;
}
```

How can I fix that?